# sudo systemctl status mysqld.service not working properly

Tags: mysql, server, centos8

Trying to install mysql server on centos 8.
and after using

> sudo systemctl status mysqld.service

getting this picture, that is hanging for hours.

[image]

I don't understand what it means and haven't found any information about this situation.

If I'm trying to write something over there, it just makes a weird sound.

The problem is that I can't get out of there. The process is running and not giving to do anything else.

Comment: Why do you think there's a problem? It says "Server is operational"

Comment: The problem is that I can't get out of there. The process is running and not giving to do anything else.

Comment: Type `q` to get out of the pager.

Comment: It's piping the output to `less`, so it's just like when you use `less filename`.

Comment: Barmar, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your status, it's clearly shown that it's working fine. Nothing worry about.

Comment: The problem is that I can't get out of there. The process is running and not giving to do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

To stop a process in linux terminal simply click Ctrl + c at once that should end any process in linux terminal @liza

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).